# OpenLDAP Integration

Tags: ubuntu, openldap

I have installed an OpenLDAP server on an AWS EC2 Ubuntu 16.04 instance.

It's working fine while my client machine is connected to the internet, but whenever I am disconnecting internet from client machine then I am unable to login with the LDAP user.

Answer (score 0):

LDAP accounts naturally need information from LDAP in order to work. So you have two options:

- Switch to an LDAP client that has persistent on-disk caching – the main option is SSSD (which completely replaces pam_ldap / libnss_ldap and all associated configuration).
- Add separate caching modules for both PAM and nsswitch which run before the LDAP client modules. For PAM you can use pam_ccreds; for NSS you can either run the nscd daemon (note that it needs on-disk caching to be manually enabled) or use nss-updatedb to periodically generate a local copy.

See also:

- http://people.skolelinux.org/pere/blog/Caching_password__user_and_group_on_a_roaming_Debian_laptop.html

Comment: It's still not working, can you please just brief some more about it or any reference for step to step configuration of sssd